# Can galaxy formation process explain Tully-Fisher relation in dark matter theory?

Tags: galaxy, dark-matter

I read that, unlike MOND theory, [Tully-Fisher relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tully%E2%80%93Fisher_relation) is believed to result from galaxy formation in dark matter theory. What is the exact current status regarding the explanation of Tully-Fisher relation from galaxy formation process?

Comment: do you remember where you have read it?